# how to display headerkey options in struts2 jquery grid column

Tags: struts2, struts2-jquery, jquery-select2

i have a jsp page where i am displaying data in strust2 jquery Grid. 
In  grid column there is search facility based on the Select type(Drop down select).

```
<sjg:gridColumn name="subjectId" title="Subject Name" editable="true" align="center" search="true" searchtype="select" 
 searchoptions="{dataUrl:'%{selecturl}'}"  edittype="select"     editoptions="{dataUrl:'%{selecturl}'}"  />
```

.My dropdown list is coming fine from my Class as well as it is correctly displaying on its place.

What i want exactly is a header value something like this ( ----select here--) followed by all the values populated from my class.

eg. I know how to do this(below code) in struts2 but i don't know this in struts2 jquery grid column.Now i am only able to display all list without header key & header values.

```
<s:select label="What's your favor search engine" 
    headerKey="-1" headerValue="----Select here----"
    list="selecturl" 
    name="name" />
```

Please help me regarding this issue.

Comment: there is nothing like that, why not just put the first element as the header option in `%{selecturl}`

Comment: I would prefer creating my own search form, since the grid search form lacks various abilities and is limited. Please see my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13218775/dynamic-data-reload-to-struts2-jquery-grid-on-form-submit/13221007#13221007 on how to populate grid based on a form fields and then you might be able to implement that in your case.

Comment: @xCoder: That is fine i know. But i want to implement like above. Only problem is i an unable to set header key in it.

Comment: @Jaiwo99 That will be not fine. It will be static.

Comment: tell me please, how could it possible be static, you can put everything you want to the first slot of the collection

Comment: @Jaiwo99 Please little explain your suggestion using code....