# dynamic data reload to struts2 jquery grid on form submit

Tags: struts2, struts2-jquery, jqgrid

I have a grid which load data on page load.
I also have a form that on submit calls an action correctly, but it doesn't load new data on my grid.

List is  correctly geting and also correctly setting in my grid model From my Action class but while on return SUCCESS it simply returns data in  this form(see below output)...

```
{"authFirstname":null,"authLastname":null,"bookDetailsobj":null,"bookTitile":null,"get":{"authFirstname":null,"authLastname":null,"bookTitile":null,"coverId":null,"createdDate":null,"createrId":null,"description":null,"editionId":null,"editionYear":null,"id":null,"img1":null,"img2":null,"isbn":null,"languageId":null,"locationId":null,"price":null,"publisherName":null,"quantity":null,"remarks":null,"subjectId":null,"updateId":null,"updatedDate":null,"videoUrl":null},"gridModel":[{"authFirstname":"234234","authLastname":"2323423","bookTitile":"23324234234","coverId":"soft cover","description":"243234","editionId":"General Edition","editionYear":"234234","id":42,"img1":"","img2":"","isbn":"324234","languageId":"English","locationId":"as","price":2.34234E7,"publisherName":"234234","quantity":234234,"remarks":"","subjectId":"General Fiction","videoUrl":""},{"authFirstname":"2423","authLastname":"23423","bookTitile":"asdfsdaf","coverId":"soft cover","description":"","editionId":"General Edition","editionYear":"2","id":39,"img1":"","img2":"","isbn":"2","languageId":"English","locationId":"as","price":234.0,"publisherName":"2","quantity":2,"remarks":"","subjectId":"General Fiction","videoUrl":""},{"authFirstname":"3","authLastname":"3","bookTitile":"232","coverId":"soft cover","description":"","editionId":"General"}
```

My jsp code:

```
         <sjg:grid
                id="getLogs"
                dataType="json"
                href="%{getCurrentDateLogs}"
                gridModel="listOfLogs"
                onSelectRowTopics="rowselect"
                loadonce="true"
                reloadTopics="reloadGrid"
                formIds="form2"
            >
            <sjg:gridColumn name="userid" index="userid" title="User ID" sortable="true" align="center"/>
            <sjg:gridColumn name="username" index="username" title="Username" sortable="true"/>
            <sjg:gridColumn name="logaction" index="logaction" width="600" title="Action" sortable="true"/>
            <sjg:gridColumn name="date" index="date" title="Date" sortable="true" sorttype="date" align="center"/>
            <sjg:gridColumn name="time" index="time" title="Time" sortable="true" sorttype="time" align="center"/>
         </sjg:grid>

         <s:form action="getLogsByDates" id="form2"  theme="simple" cssClass="yform">
            <table class="">
                <tr><td>from:</td>
                    <td><sj:datepicker value="yesterday" id="from" name="startDate" displayFormat="dd/mm/yy" label="from" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr><td>to:</td>
                    <td><sj:datepicker value="today" id="to" name="endDate" displayFormat="dd/mm/yy" label="to" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr><td colspan="2">
                <sj:submit
                    value="Search"
                    button="true"
                        onClickTopics="reloadGrid"
                    indicator="indicator"
                    />
                </td></tr>
            </table>
         </s:form>
```

struts.xml

```
 <action name="getLogsByDates" class="v.esoft.actions.bookdetails.BookdetailsAction" >
            <result name="success"  type="json"/>
            <result name="login" type="redirect"> /index.jsp </result>
   </action>
```

**
I don't know why my output is not showing in my jquery grid. Please help me**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess this is what you require :

1. Instead of using a sj:submit tag, use a sj:a tag with onClickTopics pointing to GridReloadTopics.
2. Then when sj:a is clicked, the grid get's reloaded, submitting the form to action defined in href attribute of grid.
3. This action must result a JSON which will populate the grid.

You haven't shown the action "getCurrentDateLogs" in the question. So this is the action that must return the json result populating the grid.

Also you must be thinking that how the grid-data gets affected by the form fields, so it's easy

1. The grid submits all the form fields to the action mentioned in href, so you must be having a getter & setter for every form field on that action.
2. Along with other normal grid attributes, now you'll receive the additional form attributes, based on the value of which you'll fill up the gridModel.

Please let me know if you still didnt' understood.

Comment: New Doubt:  Now my action is calling when i click on the <sj:a  button. Instead of this, Is it possible to submit this form "when users type anything in the search textfield using onkeyup or likewise?

Comment: yeah, you can do this too. You can use the onblur event of textfield and in that you can publish the grid reloadTopics. Let me know if you need an example.

Comment: Please provide me a example for this( onblur event of textfield for submiting my form....).

Comment: the grid reload topics are "reloadGrid" and your onblur should be reloadMyGrid() and there must be a javascript function by this name which contains $.publish('reloadGrid');

Comment: i tried but still it is not happening. javascript: `function reloadMyGrid()
       {
        $.publish('reloadGrid'); 
       }`   & my form is :   `<s:form action="#" id="form2"  theme="simple">
            <sj:textfield  placeholder="Enter keyword to search" onBlurTopics="reloadGrid" onblur="reloadMyGrid()" size="32" maxLength="255" name="keywordsearch"/> 
              <sj:a button="true" id="btnid"  cssStyle="position: relative;top: 0px;left: 09px;" onClickTopics="reloadMyGrid">Find</sj:a> 
         </s:form> `

Comment: the onBlurTopis are wrong, they should be same as sj:a onClickTopics

Comment: i changed to  `<sj:textfield onblur="reloadMyGrid"` from  `<sj:textfield onblur="reloadMyGrid()"`  . But still it is not happening..

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work this way. try do the following things:

1. make an action retuen a page, not json

   ```
   <result name="success">page_with_the_grid.jsp</result>
   ```
2. on the page `page_with_the_grid.jsp`, use `s:url` tag to map your json result:

   ```
   <s:url var="jsonUrl" action="jsonAction"/>
   ```
3. in your `sj:grid`, use `href="%{jsonUrl}"` to fill your data to the grid.

if you directly call the action, which returns `JSON`, you will sure get a json result, which is your "Strange" output.

Comment: now my code is working fine. just i replace submit button with <sj:a>. Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

I have find Two grid after submit the form one is old one and second one my search grid it also  include whole page

```
<sj:a  href="%{form}" targets="result" indicator="indicator" button="true" buttonIcon="ui-icon-refresh"/>
```